# C#: AutoMapper definition is working by Web APi 2 - collection element is not ignored

Tags: automapper

Im using AutoMapper with EF & Web API 2. Command

```
tempValue = Mapper.Map<MwbePaymentMethodDtoInOut>(res);
```

seems to not work. The result object should be object without Payments element , because it's ignored by AutoMapper definition (line: .ForSourceMember(src => src.Payments, opt => opt.Ignore())).

Global.asax

```
Namespace MobileWallet.Api
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            StartAutomapper();            
        }



        private void StartAutomapper(){
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {                
                AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
            });
        }    
    }
}
```

AutoMapper definition

```
public class MwbeToDomain : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get
        {
            return "MwbeToDomainMapping";
        }
    }
    protected override void Configure() 
    {            
        CreateMap<MwbePaymentMethod, MwbePaymentMethodDtoInOut>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.methodType, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<EnumToStringResolver<MwbePaymentMethod.MethodTypeEnum>>().FromMember(source => source.MethodType))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BillingAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.BillingAddress))
                .ForSourceMember(source => source.UserData, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.expirationdate, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DateTimeToString>().FromMember(source => source.ExpirationDate))
                .ForSourceMember(src => src.Payments, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForSourceMember(src => src.Number, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

ADDED:

I added AutoMapper validation right after setting configuration:

```
private void StartAutomapper(){

            //Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {                
                AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
            });

            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
```

Validation code is started by app, but no errors is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, my "stupid" fault :).

I had to remove ignored property from destination class. When property was there, it was not ignored by AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

First try adding `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();`

[**AutoMapper**: Configuration Validation](https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Configuration%20Validation)

Comment: Your tip is ok, it works on separate solution and it was exaclty the same I have in code:). I think so:). SO the problem in initialization of AutoMapper

Answer (score 0):

I might not be reading this right, but I'm not sure what AutoMapperConfiguration is.  Since you are creating a profile, I think you need to tell AutoMapper about it so it knows to use it.  Try changing your StartAutomapper function to something like this:

```
private void StartAutomapper()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {                
        cfg.AddProfile<MwbeToDomain>();
    });

    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

Also, it might help to put a breakpoint in the Profile's Configure method to make sure that it is getting called.

Comment: Yes, I was debugging and it was called.